# List of possible 'changes' values in Facebook Realtime Update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I've implemented this for my site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0

and I am receiving updates successfully. The format of these updates is fairly easy to understand by understanding the JSON response. However, I can't find a list of possible types of changes (possible values for the JSON response) so I can handle / replicate all the scenarios that may come up.

Is this published anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with *types of changes* exactly. There's

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#subscribefields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#receiveupdates

If you click on the first links down arrows on the right side, you'll get the list of fields that can change for the `user` and the `page` objects.

After some searching, I came across https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed#updates There's a reference to http://activitystrea.ms/ in the code:

```
<activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/post/</activity:verb>
```

Unfortunately, the website doesn't work apparantly, but one can view an old version here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140720095121/http://activitystrea.ms/registry/verbs/

This seems to contain the list of possible verbs wihtin this schema. Which of those Facebook actually uses is not clear to me unfortunately. There's the specs as well: http://activitystrea.ms/specs/json/schema/activity-schema.html#verbs

Comment: So the 2nd link you posted explains what the response looks like, but it doesn't enumerate the possibilities of what "changes" might contain. For example, I am seeing: changes.value.item = (comment|like), changes.value.verb = (edit|add|unlike|like|remove), etc. Depending on the thing that was changed, there are a ton of possible change.value.item and change.value.verb values.

Comment: You're right, there's nothing mentioned in the docs. After searching the FB developer page, it seems that this uses the activitystrea.ms schema. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The possible values for 'item' and 'verb' are not documented. Here's everything I have observed when receiving updates for *pages only*:

Items:

- like
- share
- comment
- photo
- video
- post

Verbs:

- add
- remove
- edited
- hide
- unhide

Can't claim this is comprehensive, but that's the best of my knowledge based on reviewing logs of many thousands of updates. I would guess that *user*, *permissions*, and *payments* RTUS have their own sets of possible values.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's basically the only list I've been able to find online.

I've noticed that editing a post actually gives me the "add" verb, and hiding/unhiding isn't triggering the callback at all. Also, the "post" item for me is only when user's post to the page timeline, and "status" is the item value when the post is by the page

Comment: @steve yeah, i've observed similar oddness. Some behaviors differ depending on if it's a wall post vs. status vs. comment. iirc, hide/unhide events definitely seen on comments.